# Does there exist $P$ such that $PP^{\dagger}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} I & 0\\ 0 & -I \end{array}\right)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Does there exist $P$ such that $PP^{\dagger}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
> I & 0\\
> 0 & -I
> \end{array}\right)$?

Here $P^{\dagger}$ is the hermitian of $P$, and $I$ means a $N\times N$
identity matrix.

It's obvious that if $N=1$, such matrix $P$ doesn't exist, I wonder whether
$P$ exists for $N\neq1$.

The condition for this matrix somehow looks like the condition for unitary matrix, if it exists, does it have a name?

Comment: Are complex number entries allowed?

Comment: Yes, the field considered is complex field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually impossible.  The reason for this is that the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$ must be positive definite.  Therefore for any complex-valued matrix $P$ and $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ we have

$$
\left \langle PP^\dagger x, x \right \rangle \;\; =\;\; \left \langle P^\dagger x, P^\dagger x \right \rangle \;\; =\;\; \left |\left |P^\dagger x \right |\right |^2 \;\; \geq \;\; 0.
$$

If $PP^\dagger$ had the form you described in your prompt, then that would mean there would be eigenvectors $v$ of $PP^\dagger$ corresponding to eigenvalue $-1$, which means that $\left \langle PP^\dagger v, v \right \rangle = \langle -v,v\rangle = - ||v||^2$, which contradicts the positive-definiteness of the norm.